# How can I access a Class instance with a certain Class attribute value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I am working on making a text-based RPG in Python, and am trying to set up the map and player movement. However, I haven't figured out how to 'link' rooms so that the player can seamlessly move from one room to another using commands such as north, south, etc.

I am using a class called 'Room' that has x-coordinate and y-coordinate attributes. I have made instances of each 'tile' in the map, with certain x-pos and y-pos values. What I'm trying to do is go to the current instance of the 'Room' class depending on what the current x-pos or y-pos are. However, I don't know how to find a class instance based upon an attribute value.

Below is my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self,name,info,xpos,ypos,exits):
        self.instances.append(self)
        self.name = name
        self.info = info
        self.xpos = xpos
        self.ypos = ypos
        self.exits = exits
```

For reference, `room.exits` is which parts of the room you can exit from. This might be only 's' and 'n', meaning there are walls to the east and west.

For further reference, on the code below, `cloc` stands for the current location. I currently have it set to:

```
intro_room = Room("Living Room of House", "You are in a dusty living room, in a stranger's house. You don't know how you got here. It's hard to see and your hands are tied", 100, 100, ['s','n'])
cloc = intro_room
```

Another snippet of code:

```
def inp():
    basic = input(">")
    if basic ==  'i':
        print(" ")
        print("This is what is in your current inventory", inventory)
    elif basic == 'h':
        print(" ")
        ### use this when programming actual game
        print("Available commands:\n-move\n-take\n-look\n-talk\n-use\n-enter")
    elif basic == 'm':
        print(" ")
        print(current_location)
    elif basic == 'description':
        print(cloc.name, cloc.info)
    elif basic == 'n':
        cloc = Room.get(ypos==ypos+1) ###try to access instance with certain instance attribute value???
        #etc. for 's', 'e', 'w'
```

The code above doesn't work, because I don't know how to perform the map movement.

Comment: @usr2564301 it is the edges of a room that you can leave from, like south or north. I wanted it to be so that if their choices isn't in the room.exits, you can't exit from there. Thank you for asking for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could organize all your rooms in a `dict`, where the key would be the 2-tuple `(xpos, ypos)`. Then, depending on your `exits`, you could exit into different rooms.

```
all_rooms = {
   (0, 0): Room(..., xpos=0, ypos=0, ...),
   (0, 1): Room(..., xpos=0, ypos=1, ...),
   ...
}

def inp():
    ...
    elif basic == "move":
        direction = input(f"Which direction? Your options are {cloc.exits}. \n>")
        if direction in cloc.exits:
            # determine new coordinate set based on direction
            new_loc = {
                'n': (cloc.xpos, cloc.ypos + 1),
                's': (cloc.xpos, cloc.ypos - 1),
                'e': (cloc.xpos + 1, cloc.ypos),
                'w': (cloc.xpos - 1, cloc.ypos),
            }[direction]
            # change current location to the new room
            cloc = all_rooms[new_loc]
        else:
            print("You can't move in that direction.")
    elif ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t really do

```
cloc = Room.get(ypos==ypos+1)
```

You should create separate methods for getting  and setting class attributes like so:

```
def getY(self):
    return self.ypos

def setY(self, ypos):
    self.ypos = ypos

#do the same for xpos
```

so

```
cloc = Room.get(ypos==ypos+1)
```

becomes

```
currentY = cloc.getY()
cloc.setY(currentY += 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best choice is separated logic for store Rooms in other class for example:

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self,name,info,xpos,ypos,exits):
        self.name = name
        self.info = info
        self.xpos = xpos
        self.ypos = ypos
        self.exits = exits

class RoomCollection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rooms = []

    def add(self, room):
        self.rooms.append(room)

    def find_by_xpos(self, xpos):
        for room in self.rooms:
            if(xpos == room.xpos):
                return room
        return None

intro_room = Room("Living Room of House", "You are in a dusty living room, in a stranger's house. You don't know how you got here. It's hard to see and your hands are tied", 100, 100, ['s','n'])

all_rooms = RoomCollection()
all_rooms.add(intro_room)

room = all_rooms.find_by_xpos(100)

print(room.name)
```